# Go: Create io.Writer inteface for logging to mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, logging, go

Using go (golang):

Is there a way to create a logger that outputs to a database?

Or more precisely, can I implement some kind of io.Writer interface that I can pass as the first argument to `log.New()`?

EG: (dbLogger would receive the output of the log and write it to the database)

`logger := log.New(dbLogger, "dbLog: ", log.Lshortfile)
logger.Print("This message will be stored in the database")`

I would assume that **I should just create my own database logging function**, but I was curious to see if there is already a way of doing this using the existing tools in the language.

For some context, I'm using [mgo.v2](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2) to handle my mongodb database, but I don't see any io.Writer interfaces there other than in [GridFS](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#GridFS), which I think solves a different problem.

I'm also still getting my head around the language, so I may have used some terms above incorrecly. Any corrections are very welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is easily doable, because the [`log.Logger`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger) type guarantees that each log message is delivered to the destination [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) with a single `Writer.Write()` call:

> Each logging operation makes a single call to the Writer's Write method. A Logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines; it guarantees to serialize access to the Writer.

So basically you just need to create a type which implements `io.Writer`, and whose `Write()` method creates a new document with the contents of the byte slice, and saves it in the MongoDB.

Here's a simple implementation which does that:

```
type MongoWriter struct {
    sess *mgo.Session
}

func (mw *MongoWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    c := mw.sess.DB("").C("log")
    err = c.Insert(bson.M{
        "created": time.Now(),
        "msg":     string(p),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    return len(p), nil
}
```

Using it:

```
sess := ... // Get a MongoDB session

mw := &MongoWriter{sess}
log.SetOutput(mw)

// Now the default Logger of the log package uses our MongoWriter.
// Generate a log message that will be inserted into MongoDB:
log.Println("I'm the first log message.")
log.Println("I'm multi-line,\nbut will still be in a single log message.")
```

Obviously if you're using another `log.Logger` instance, set the `MongoWriter` to that, e.g.:

```
mylogger := log.New(mw, "", 0)
mylogger.Println("Custom logger")
```

Note that the log messages end with newline as `log.Logger` appends it even if the log message itself does not end with newline. If you don't want to log the ending newline, you may simply cut it, e.g.:

```
func (mw *MongoWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    origLen := len(p)
    if len(p) > 0 && p[len(p)-1] == '\n' {
        p = p[:len(p)-1] // Cut terminating newline
    }

    c := mw.sess.DB("").C("log")

    // ... the rest is the same

    return origLen, nil // Must return original length (we resliced p)
}
```

Comment: That's great! I assume we can't handle additional arguments in Write function because all that method can receive is one byte slice correct? It would be great to send additional arguments into that function, like stacktrace, or other important data, but we would have to send it through that byte slice and then split it right?

Comment: @17xande Correct, the `Write()` method takes nothing but a byte slice. You can access the stack trace from `Write()` too, that's not a problem (see [`runtime.Callers()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller) and [`runtime.CallersFrames()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#CallersFrames)). If you want other important data to be logged, then include them in the log message (e.g. pass them to `Logger.Printf()`).