# Should I close file while writing/reading concurrently?

Tags: file, go, concurrency

I'm making a server that can read/write from file concurrently(from goroutines populated by `net/http` handlers). I've created The following struct:

```
type transactionsFile struct {
    File  *os.File
    Mutex *sync.RWMutex
}
```

I'm initializing file once at the `init()` function. Should I close it somehow on each writing operation?

Comment: If you close the file, you will have to open it again at the beginning of your handler.

Comment: @Abdullah that's why I'm asking) Is it safe not to close the file?

Comment: `Should I close it somehow on each writing operation?` this is very specific to the use case. However, don t forget to sync to make sure data is written on disk, see https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write to a closed file, so if you close it after each write operation, you also have to (re)open it before each write.

This would be quite inefficient. So instead leave it open, and only close it once your app is about to terminate (this is required because [`File.Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write) does not guarantee that when it returns the data is written to disk). Since you're writing the file from HTTP handlers, you should implement graceful server termination, and close the file after that. See [`Server.Shutdown()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown) for details.

Also, if the purpose of your shared file writing is to create some kind of logger, you could take advantage of the [`log`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) package, so you would not have to use a mutex. For details, see [net/http set custom logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294334/net-http-set-custom-logger/52298092#52298092).

Comment: Does `Write()` guarantees that changes will be saved? Isn't it `Close()`'s responsibility?

Comment: @SailorMoon Yes, there is no guarantee that when `File.Write()` returns the data is written to the underlying storage unit.

Comment: Neither `Write()` nor `Close()` guarantee that the changes are actually written. You can use `Sync()` and check the returned error before closing the file.

Comment: @Abdullah Yes, it does not guarantee that the data written will appear on the disk right away. But if `Close()` does not return an error, the data will be written to disk eventually, even if the app terminates.

Comment: @icza Yes, this is true unless there is a disk failure which is a bigger problem all together.